# mapply for a single list

Tags: r, mapping, mapply

I understand the usage of `mapply(FUN, ...)` that cycles through elements of each of the `...` arguments and applies `FUN` to those combinations. What if instead of multiple arguments in `...` I have them in one list?

**Example use case**:
I define a function that pastes arguments excluding `NA`:

```
pasteNotNA <- function(...,collapse=', '){
  dots <- list(...);
  paste(na.omit(unlist(dots)),collapse=collapse)
}

pasteNotNA('a',NA,'c')
# "a, c"
```

I can apply it element-wise for vectors if I pass them explicitly to `mapply`:

```
mapply(pasteNotNA, c('a',NA,'c'),c('X','Y','Z'),c('1','2',NA),USE.NAMES = F)
# "a, X, 1"   "Y, 2"    "c, Z"
```

What I want is to apply it to a list and get the same result:

```
inp_list <- list(vec1=c('a',NA,'c'), vec2=c('X','Y','Z'), vec3=c('1','2',NA))
some_apply(pasteNotNA, inp_list)
# "a, X, 1"   "Y, 2"    "c, Z"
```

I guess it must be also something from `*apply()` or `Map()` family but can't find the good solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Use `do.call` :

```
do.call("mapply", c(pasteNotNA, inp_list, USE.NAMES = FALSE))
## [1] "a, X, 1" "Y, 2"    "c, Z"
```

**2)** or use `pmap_chr` in the purrr package:

```
library(purrr)

pmap_chr(inp_list, pasteNotNA)
## [1] "a, X, 1" "Y, 2"    "c, Z"
```

**3)** This also works:

```
apply(as.data.frame(inp_list), 1, pasteNotNA)
## [1] "a, X, 1" "Y, 2"    "c, Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `unite`, which already have `na.rm` argument

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
as_tibble(inp_list) %>% 
  unite(vec, everything(), na.rm = TRUE, sep =", ")
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  vec    
  <chr>  
1 a, X, 1
2 Y, 2   
3 c, Z
```